# что такое NGINX и как его найти?

Tags: nginx, apache, сервер, веб-сервер

Всем привет, я недавно в веб разработке (фронтенд) и никогда не понимал что такое NGINX, гугля и спрашивая у людей я слышу такой ответ: "Это веб-сервер который принимает и обрабатывает твои запросы" и ничего больше (в пример обычно приводится как-раз таки код веб-серверов на каком-либо языке). Но я не до конца улавливаю суть "Nginx" в понятии веб-сервер.

К примеру у меня есть сервер на NodeJS, который обслуживает статические файлы и динамические роуты. Тоесть, у меня есть полностью рабочее, функционирующее приложение.

Работа дальше написания веб-сервера (на каком-то конкретном языке) это для меня темный лес.

Объясните пожалуйста что такое "Nginx", можно ли без него? (и без Apache, который упоминают так же часто как и Nginx). Что это такое?)

Как мне пощупать Nginx, понять где или между чем он лежит (находится).

Буду очень благодарен ясному объяснению

Answer (score 1):

Ваш NodeJS, который обслуживает статические файлы и динамические роуты, тоже является web-сервером т.к. обрабатывает запросы по http(s) протоколу.

Для улучшения производительности и защищенности вашего приложения правильнее перед NodeJs поставить другой вебсервер (например Nginx)  поручить ему следующие ф-ции:

1. SSL Termination. Т.е. за шифрование будет отвечать nginx, а далее проксировать запрос уже по http без шифрования
2. Отдачу статики
3. Кеширование

Вот статейка как это сделать https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-run-a-node-js-server-with-nginx/